# My Account on SO is not Accepting Questions, What I do?

Tags: support, post-ban

You have reached your question limit

Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: is there any way to overcome from this problem or not ?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation provided instead of asking others for help. That's really the core of using SO, if you ask here without reading you're bound to get question banned.

Comment: @yivi I voted to close as organically as one can. I read the question, found the dupe, and voted to close. If there is history beyond that that should preclude the closure of this question, a comment or edit to the question (or an answer) would be a good idea. I don't make a habit of checking the history of every question I close...

Comment: One major issue is deleting the question 12 minutes after it was posted. Not sure how a user is supposed to easily find the advice we give here when the question is deleted so quickly.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker There's...always the link in the message itself that blocks them.  Granted, that one's harder to find, but not *that* difficult.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If this user asked how to improve his questions, undeleting it would be fine. But he is not. He is asking how to get out of his question ban without showing any evidence of having even read the duplicate

Comment: @ErikA He asked in the comments.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Not any comments I can see...

Comment: @ErikA I even left the comment where you responded to him because that was the most complete comment (all the others said the exact same thing, but in different ways).

Comment: @George All comments I saw was just repeating the question over and over again in slightly different wording, without acknowledging a problem with his question quality or asking how to improve it. That's why I pointed him to the duplicate, and suggested that he'd best read it.

Comment: This question shows no research effort. Its only answer contains information that's either 1. provided to people along with the question ban banner (I hope), or 2. specifically tailored to the asker's problem. As such the Q&A does not seem to help future readers. If OP can't see their recent deleted question (I thought they could) then a mod ping could guide them back here. Do we really need yet another non-informative dupe to the question ban FAQ that nobody who needs it will read? The FAQ currently has 180 linked questions, I bet a significant chunk of those are duplicates.

Comment: @andras meta is a support site. It doesn’t make sense to delete support information.

Answer (score -6):

You have several downvoted questions that have caused you to become question banned, as the [linked duplicate suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Your options are to:

1. Do nothing.
2. Try to resolve the issues with your questions that caused them to be downvoted.

I'll address the deleted questions here first, since those are difficult or impossible to find depending on their age:

---

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334354/in-php-mysql-display-session-variable-in-dashboard-page-in-login-with-jquery-aja

  Closed as a duplicate.  You'd be able to tell if the listed duplicate does solve your issue or not. If it doesn't, edit this question to indicate what's different from the listed duplicate.

---

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192910/what-is-use-of-exit-in-php-and-difference-between-them

  Self deleted.  Deleted questions' score are considered when applying a question ban; so this question counts against you.  You can clean up the question and undelete it. There's a reasonable question here, but the grammar and punctuation may've made it hard for some readers to parse what you were asking, so please review the edits for an example of how you might format your questions to improve their readability.

---

- [In PHP & MySQL Display date in day month Year Format from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283196/in-php-mysql-display-date-in-day-month-year-format-from-database)

  This question was likely downvoted because you included the code as an image. Code needs to be text inside of your question, not pasted as an image.  You can use three backticks (```) to surround the code to ensure it's formatted as code.

---

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56010112/in-php-mysql-data-is-entered-in-database-when-input-fields-value-with-form-submi

  This was a pretty good question; I am unclear as to why you deleted it. Consider that a downvote may mean only that (as mentioned above) some readers are struggling with your formatting: a little bit of time spent on improving the structure of the question may be all that is needed to remedy this.

---

- [How to combine data from two tables with no common fields in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916300/how-to-combine-data-from-two-tables-with-no-common-fields-in-sql)

  This is a pretty good question! You included details on your research, provided detailed examples of what you were trying to achieve... All that could be improved here is, once again, formatting and punctuation. See edits for an example of how you might improve that.

---

- [Text & image is not inserted into database through bootstrap modal without page refresh in php mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481491/text-image-is-not-inserted-into-database-through-bootstrap-modal-without-page)

  This question could be made better by clearly describing the behavior you're seeing and any errors you get. "Doesn't work" is hard for us to parse.

---

All in all, a little elbow grease and [some reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) should help you understand the actions you need to take to have your question ban removed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199088/discussion-on-answer-by-george-stocker-my-account-on-so-is-not-accepting-questio).

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the edit! Love it.